# Set width for span element without being absolute

Tags: css

I am looking for a way to avoid having the table jiggle around as in the following:
[image]

I understand it is because of the hours changing it's number of digits. So is there a way I could set the width based on the font size and the widest `XX.XX` could ever be?

I could always change it to 'hours' instead of 'hrs', but I am a bit partial to 'hrs, and am just curious. Also if you were on a large enough screen it would go onto one line and the problem would persist.

Thanks

Edit:
Here's a minimum code example [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j85zkqt0/1/)

Comment: You could change the display to inline-block then you can set it's width;

Comment: Could you share your “*[mcve]*” code so that we can easily reproduce your problem, and offer practicable answers?

Comment: its a react app but ill try to add just the html and you can manually change the values

Answer (score 0):

`span` is an inline element and has its width set to the size of its content. To be able to set the width you can set it to be an `inline-block` using `display: inline-block;`. Then, you can use either `min-width` or `width` to accomplish what you want to do here.

[W3Schools has a great resource](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp) on the display property, and how different block elements work with different display properties.

Comment: Am aware of all this, was asking how to set the with based on character size

Comment: em is a css unit that might help, or ch is the width of a '0'. em is more commonly used.